# dhtmlx scheduler and database

Tags: database-design, dhtmlx-scheduler

i use dhtmlx scheduler with mvc razor.
I want to get the inputs for setting start time and endtime with the values from database instead of manually entering 8 and 20 inside the code,Please guide me. I use entity framework(dbfirst)

```
scheduler.Config.first_hour = 8;
scheduler.Config.last_hour = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand your situation.

However I can offer a suggestion, will the following be possible:

- Store those values in a new table.
- Use a separate SQL query to retrieve these 2 values, which you store in variables.
- Then just set those values to point to those 2 variable.
- All the above must happen on page load and before setting those 2 values.

Hope it helps.